# Verifying Recaptcha without Plugins? -- cross server POST

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

Verifying ReCaptcha without plugins requires a POST request to be sent to http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify.

However many browsers do not allow cross server post requests to be sent. How can I still verify the ReCaptcha without plugins? Thanks.

Source: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

Comment: you don't want to use plugins or serives? you could code it on your own... but why would you do that

Comment: You've answered the question yourself. You need to do a cross server request to verify it, and browsers don't allow that. So *you cannot verify it client-side*. Either you use a plugin, or you make the request to http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify server-side yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a request from your serverside (it's exactly what the plugins do).